# Tensorflow for 1D input vector

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am a a beginner in machine learning and currently trying to learn about deep learning and convNets. I have been following the tutorials on tensorflow.org and have done the first two tutorials. But so far I have done examples of 2d input vectors (images).

My ultimate goal is to be able to train a CNN to be able recognise peaks in a spectra(which is 1d vector). Is there any tutorials/example code/suggestion as to how I should start approaching this problem?

Comment: this? https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3sw2uh/1d_convolutional_network/

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2165

Answer (score 3):

There is no actual difference, simply your convolutional kernels will be rectangular instead of square, of size 1xK (as opposed to typical KxK). Besides that there is no much of the difference.